# The select2 Library is not working: the select tag shows the traditional drop down without search feature

Tags: html, jquery-select2

I am using select2 Library for making the conventional select tag have search feature but I am not able to do so
Below is the code

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" 
  rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script>
  jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

// for making the case dropdown have search feature
   jQuery("#case_id").select2();
 });
</script>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT case_Id ,concat( 'ref',Refnumber,' case no.',CaseNumber) as caseRef FROM wp_cases     where casestatus='processing'";
if($results  = $wpdb->get_results( $sql)){
    $options ="";
     foreach($results as $row){  
       
    $options = $options."<option value=$row->case_Id>$row->caseRef</option>";
    }

}
?>

 <form method=post>
  <select id="case_id" name="case_id" class="form-control input sm " required>
   <?php echo $options; ?>
  </select>
 </form>
```

Can someone help as to what might have been the cause of the problem? or am I doing it in a wrong way?

**Edit**

The developer console shows the following errors:-

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).select2 is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):36)
at j (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Two questions: does the developer console show any errors, or are you only looking at a mobile browser?

Comment: No, I am checking it on desktop PC browser. and the developer console is showing errors. Please refer to the edited section of the question to see the error message @TiesonT.

Comment: That sounds like you've either loaded the libraries out of order or are including jQuery twice. If you're trying to use a recently released version, do note that it takes a little while for the CDN to get updated (you'd probably see a 404 in the Network tab if that's the case).

Comment: Checked the order and the repetition of jQuery library, it looks fine unless I am mistaking the order in the code. Is the order of the libraries in the above code correct? Still couldn't figure out the cause of errors showing in console @TiesonT.